# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^2 B^2=0$, then which of the following is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was doing linear algebra problems and got stuck in the following question:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^2 B^2=0$. Then which of the following option is correct? (and why?)

(a) $B^2 A^2=0$

(b) $AB=0$

(c) Either $A^2=0$ or $B^2=0$

(d) Either $A$ or $B$ has $0$ determinant

It would be helpful if any of you could provide a counterexample for the incorrect options. Thanks...

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: Either $\;A^2\;$ or $\;B^2\;$ is singular. What does this tell you about their determinants?

Comment: Use $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0}$ and some appropriate *diagonal* matrix $B$.